# Integral - Change of Variable?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Compute $\int_{x=0}^8\int_{y=x^{1/3}}^21/(y^4+1) dydx$.

Unsure what the change of variable would be?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: What did you have tried? You won't be able to get an answer here unless you tell that.

Comment: @Nightflight, I wanted to check if changing the variable would be the correct way of attempting the question. I could attempt using $x = rcos\theta \ and \ y=rsin\theta$

Comment: @f.Greening It is wrong approach. Please see my answer, be uploaded soon.

Comment: @Nightflight thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral's domain $D$ will be this set: $D=\{(x,y) \mid x^{\frac13}<y<2, 0<x<8\}$.

Change the order of the variables, then $D$ will be this form, which is neater: $D=\{(x,y) \mid 0<x<y^3, 0<y<2\}$.

Then your integral will be easily calculated.

$$
\int_0^8\int_{x^{1/3}}^2\frac1{y^4+1}dydx=\int_0^2\int_0^{y^3}\frac1{y^4+1}dxdy=\int_0^2\frac{y^3}{y^4+1}dy=\left[\frac14\ln(y^4+1)\right]_0^2=\frac14\ln17
$$

Comment: Thank you. Will need to look over changing the order of integration for future problems.